# Cannot detect the mobile operator

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
namespace Contact
{
    class Contact
    {
        private string personName, personId , mobileNumber;
        private char gender; 
        private int age;

    public Contact()
    {
        this.personName = "";
        this.personId = "";
        this.mobileNumber = "";
        this.gender = '\0';
        this.age = 0;

    }
    public Contact(string personName, string personId, string mobileNumber,char gender, int age)
    { 
          this.personName =personName ;
               this.personId =personId;
                this. mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
                this.gender=gender;
                this.age=age;

    }
    public void SetPersonName(string personName)
    {
        this.personName = personName;
    }
    public void SetPersonId(string personId)
    {
        this.personId = personId;
    }
    public void  SetMobileNumber(string mobileNumber)
    {
         this. mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
    public void SetGender(char gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public void SetAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public string GetPersonName()
    {
        return this.personName;
    }
    public string GetPersonId()
    {
        return this.personId;
    }
    public string GetMobileNumber()
    {
        return this.mobileNumber;
    }
    public char GetGender()
    {
        return this.gender;
    }
    public int GetAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }
   public void DetectMobileOperator()
    {


        if (this.mobileNumber[2] == 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Gp");
        }
        else if (this.mobileNumber[2] == 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Banglalink");
        }
        else if (this.mobileNumber[2] == 8)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Robi");
        }


    }
   public void ShowPersonInfo()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("PersonName: {0}\npersonId: {1}\nMobilenumber: {2}\nGender: {3}\nAge: {4}", this.personName, this.personId, this.mobileNumber, this.gender,this.age);
   }




}
}

namespace Contact
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         Contact c = new Contact("jerin","14255581","01782813945",'F',22);

        c.ShowPersonInfo();
        c.DetectMobileOperator();



    }
}
}
```

But I am not getting the operator name.Could you please help me.

Comment: `7` isn't the same as `'7'`

Comment: For future reference, we generally prefer *short* code samples that demonstrate the issue and have had the cruft removed (preferably a [mcve]). All of those `GetXxx` and `SetXxx` methods seem irrelevant here. (And also seem to be "Writing Java in C#"-style code - in C# we have actual properties with `get` and `set` methods)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You compare `this.mobileNumber[2]` which in a `char` to a number which is an `int`.

To solve you issue you should do the following (for example , lets compare to 7):

```
char value;
int number = 7;
char.TryParse(number.ToString(), out value);
if(this.mobileNumber[2] == value)
{

}
```

I hope you'll find it helpful

Comment: Is this an attempt to find the longest possible route between what you have and what you want? Why would you recommend converting to string and parsing rather than, say, just using `'7'` where `7` currently appears?

Comment: Using magic numbers is a bad practice. In my snippet the number 7 repesnt an int read from a field. I'll adjust my answer to better fit my explenation.